# File name validation

Tags: c#, file

I check a file name validation in the following way:

```
foreach (char c in System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
{
    validFileName = validFileName.Replace(c, '_');
}
```

Is there a faster way do do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be faster, but I hardly think the original would be slow enough to care about...

```
var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
var fileNameChars = validFileName.ToCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < fileNameChars.Length; ++i)
    if (invalidChars.Contains(fileNameChars[i]))
        fileNameChars[i] = '_';

validFileName = new string(fileNameChars);
```

Comment: Any reason you increment the index with `++i`, instead of `i++`?

Comment: @RandRandom Force of habit from olden C++ days where `++i` could be more efficient than `i++`. Makes no difference either way for C# in this usage due to optimizations, of course. But at least I know I'm being precise about whether I need the value before incrementing or not (`++i` is clear that I don't)

Comment: But wouldnt this for loop, skip the fileNameChars[0], because the ++ infront of the i means that you do the increment before you get the value? does this code reach 0. - yeah I know I could test it, but no IDE close by :)

Comment: @RandRandom No, it doesn't increment it *before* the start of the loop. It's just executed at the end of each loop iteration, so it doesn't make any difference whether you use `++i` or `i++`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) for full definition.

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with that? Two line implementation, and a stack overflow search for this shows your answer matches an accepted answer for another question [How to make a valid Windows filename from an arbitrary string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620605/how-to-make-a-valid-windows-filename-from-an-arbitrary-string)